# For loop incrementer doesn't work as index for vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, vector, indexing

I'm currently having trouble with testing my bubble sorting (I haven't finished the actual code for it yet) but when I have the vector of strings: "words[j][j]" and it doesn't print ANYTHING while doing "words[0][0]" does print something.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

vector<string>* get_words()
{
    fstream word_file;
    string input;

    vector<string>* retval = new vector<string>();
    word_file.open("word_list.txt", ios::in);

    getline(word_file, input);
    while (word_file) {

        if (input.length() != 0 && input[0] != '#') {
            retval->push_back(input);
            cout << input << endl;
        }

        getline(word_file, input);
    }

    word_file.close();
    return retval;
}

void bubbleList(vector<string>* words)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < words->size() - 1; j++) {
        cout << words[j][j] << endl; //PROBLEM IS HERE
        for (int i = j + 1; i < words->size(); i++) {
        }
    }
}

void printVector(vector<string>* printer)
{
    cout << printer << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string>* wordsList;
    wordsList = get_words();
    bubbleList(wordsList);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, the variable names are just for getting it working, don't worry. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is using pointers a requirement of your assignment?

Comment: `word` is a **pointer** to a `vector<string>`. You need `(*words)[j][j]`. But what you really should do is stop dynamically allocating your vector and passing around a pointer to it. `get_words` should return by value, and `bubbleList` should take it's argument by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`words` is a pointer. Using the index operator on a pointer treats it as an array. e.g:

```
int * i = new int[4];
i[0] = 1; // set the first element of the array
i[1] = 2; // set the second element of the array
i[2] = 3; // set the third element of the array
```

As you haven't created an array the only index you can access is the first element, this is equivalent to dereferencing the pointer. Your code should therefore be:

```
cout << words[0][j] << "\n";
```

or more conventionally:

```
cout << (*words)[j] << "\n";
```

However you don't really have any need to use a pointer in your code at all. You can return the vector by value from `get_words` and then pass it into other functions by reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> get_words()
{
    std::fstream word_file;
    std::string input;

    std::vector<std::string> retval;
    word_file.open("word_list.txt", std::ios::in);

    std::getline(word_file, input);
    while (word_file) {

        if (input.length() != 0 && input[0] != '#') {
            retval.push_back(input);
            std::cout << input << "\n";
        }

        std::getline(word_file, input);
    }

    word_file.close();
    return retval;
}

void bubbleList(std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < words.size() - 1; j++) {
        std::cout << words[j] << "\n";
        for (int i = j + 1; i < words.size(); i++) {
        }
    }
}

void printVector(const std::vector<std::string>& printer)
{
    for (auto& word : printer)
    {
        std::cout << word << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> wordsList;
    wordsList = get_words();
    bubbleList(wordsList);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `vector<string>* vec = new vector<string>();` is the dynamic version of `vector<string> vec();`

This is not making a 2 dimensional vector. When you are indexing with [0][0] you are not offsetting, this is why it is displaying. Instead of treating it as a 2d, treat it as a single dimensional with a first offset of 0: [0][j]

This line of code is creating a vector with a single row and a single column which can only grow in the column direction. This is why you have to have [0][index] when indexing it.

```
vector<string> *retval = new vector<string>();
```

If you need to have a 2d vector using pointers then what you should do is:

```
vector<string>* vec = new vector<string>[SIZE]();
```

Now you have a vector that you can index with a greater than 0 value for the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer to vector, points to a single vector. So the indexing in your loop has undefined behavior:

```
for(int j = 0; j < words->size()-1; j++){
        cout << words[j][j]<< endl;             //PROBLEM IS HERE
        for(int i = j+1; i < words->size(); i++){

    }
```

You cannot use anything except 0 here because of your new: `words[0][j]`

Didn’t get why you need a pointer to vector in the first place.